# Using classification models with trends to predict probability of failure

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification

I am wanting to build a classification model to classify events to be cat or not cat (for example). In my case, the cat or not cat would be failed state or not failed state.

However, in my application, the data that is fed into the model would be a set of measured parameters that would be measured over 14 days (temperature, pressure, run time), i.e. continuous data measured over 14 days. The data that I am comparing it to is a set of data over 14 days during a failed stated.

How do I go about this type of classification?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I essentially have a failure event, and I want to compare data to my failure event and determine a probability of how close my comparison data is to the failure data (this would be an indication of my equipment health and likelihood to fail)

Comment: _Classification_ implies creation of a forced categorical choice and should seldom be the goal of an analysis, as opposed to probability estimation.    What you seem to need is a longitudinal binary logistic model with time-dependent covariates.